# Separate posts by chapter per rewrite

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have an unresolved problem, please help me. I use Wordpress.

Myurl `index.php?story=slug_story&chapter=id_parent-slug_chapter`

My code

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^name/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?story=$matches[1]&chapter=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

}, 1, 1 );
```

My result `name/slug_story/id_parent-slug_chapter` => Working for me.

But how can I rewrite URLs => `name/slug_story/slug_chapter` ?

---

I use `post_parent` in `wp_posts` to connect post_type `story` vs `chapter`. Tried your code @simongcc, but not working.

```
add_filter( 'request', 'q363618_modify_request_query' ) ;
function q363618_modify_request_query( $query ) {
    global $wp_rewrite, $post;

    if (   ! isset( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! is_object( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() 
        || ! isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) 
    ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $post->post_type == 'chapter' ){
        if ( empty(get_post($post->post_parent)->post_name))  {

        } else {
            $parentName = get_post($post->post_parent)->post_name;
            $slug = $post->post_name;
            // preg_match('#[0-9]-(.*)#', $slug, $slug);
            // $slug = $slug[1];
            $query['chapter'] = $slug;

        }
    }
    return $query; // after that, WordPress will think slug_chapter = id_parent-slug_chapter
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'q363618_redirect_to_permalink' );
function q363618_redirect_to_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite, $wp, $post;

    if (   ! isset( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! is_object( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() 
        || ! isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) 
    ) {
        return;
    }

    if( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['chapter'] ) ) { 

        if ( $post->post_type == 'chapter' ){
            if ( empty(get_post($post->post_parent)->post_name))  {

            } else {
                $parentName = get_post($post->post_parent)->post_name;
                $slug = $post->post_name;
                preg_match('#[0-9]-(.*)#', $slug, $slug);
                $slug = $slug[1];

                $redirect = home_url( 'name/'.$parentName.'/' . $slug );
                wp_redirect( $redirect );    
            }
        }

    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Eesults returned 404 not found, and i updated permalink in wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

Since rewrite topics is something requiring tedious testing and time. And it is not something that 1 answer - 1 code

- complete because it involves many unknown factors from the asker such as
- how does the post type is created, settings in query_var which affects the query param
- is there any plugins involved
- what other coding or settings such as page structure and so on

So usually if asker could give more information could help.

For different audience sake, I add some more notes here based on @Tom J Nowell suggested.
The following suggestions assumed that you are

- familiar with php
- feel comfortable to trace and tweak WordPress source files
- further debugging procedures are probably required
- patience to read and test

Please allow me to copy the asker code here and refactor the description for better explanations.

I assumed it is working where `story` and `chapter` are allowed in WordPress already by the developer settings somewhere in the code.

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^name/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?story=$matches[1]&chapter=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

}, 1, 1 );
```

This code means to interpret

`http//example.com/name/slug_story/id_parent-slug_chapter`

as `index.php?story=slug_story&chapter=id_parent-slug_chapter`

So it will interpret

`http//example.com/name/slug_story/slug_chapter`

as `index.php?story=slug_story&chapter=slug_chapter`

In the WordPress rewrite system,

- It parse the the URL, transform it into query parameters and always the first thing to do. That's why a simple redirect will not work.
- If anything found, it will load the template. If not it load a 404 template.

So for instance, WordPress will try to look up `chapter=slug_chapter` but it does not exist. Because the real name is `id_parent-slug_chapter`.

So the concept to make it working, you need to tell WordPress that

`slug_chapter` = `id_parent-slug_chapter`

After understanding it, here is the possible solutions which I have done successfully. 2 steps

- tell WordPress **slug_chapter** is equal to **id_parent-slug_chapter**
- redirect **id_parent-slug_chapter** to **slug_chapter**

*** But here, I assumed that other query parameters that WordPress received are same for both link other than `chapter`. If there is any other difference. You may have to read further for debugging a 404 result.**

Since I am not sure the logic behind the asker's post name.
The magic checking is left for the asker.

```
// Part (A)
// This filter means to modify the query before it pass for matching a template
// so this is useful for customisation

add_filter( 'request', 'q363618_modify_request_query' ) );
function q363618_modify_request_query( $query ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // no need to run if permalink is not being used
    if (   ! isset( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! is_object( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() 
        || ! isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) 
        // add more checking if you need
    ) {
        return;
    }

    // add your magic here
    // after the chapter name, eg. you may have a way to compare and transform them
    // tell WordPress slug_chapter = id_parent-slug_chapter

    $query['chapter'] = 'id_parent-slug_chapter'; // you may put some static value to test if this filter works for you, if it works, together with the following redirect filter, it will redirect to where you expect

    // eg. try to use a static value like $query['chapter'] = '14-story1' to see if it takes effect;

    return $query; // after that, WordPress will think slug_chapter = id_parent-slug_chapter
}
```

After WordPress recognising the `chapter` in Part (A).
It will most likely work. (Because there are still case by case scenario that I might haven't taken account with, so I cannot guarantee that it will plug and go)

```
// Part (B)
// This only do redirect, redirect itself is 100% working if the logic and conditions is right. If Part (A) fail, it will still redirect to 404.

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'q363618_redirect_to_permalink' );
function q363618_redirect_to_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    if (   ! isset( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! is_object( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() 
        || ! isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) 
    ) {
        return;
    }

    // check query
    if( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['chapter'] ) ) { // example only, you can add required conditions

        // check url
        // if found any pattern `/name/slug_story/id_parent-slug_chapter`
        // change it to `/name/slug_story/slug_chapter`
        // this part redirect url only, part (A) is important that it tell WordPress what template to match

        $redirect = home_url( '/name/slug_story/slug_chapter' );

        wp_redirect( $redirect );
    } else {
        // do not affect other pages
        return;
    }
}
```

#### 404 Tracing

If it is still going to 404, the you need to trace for the reason. Because there are many cases, different query parameters are involved. A tracing could ensure which part is missing. And then you just fill the missing parts and make it working.

The checking logic of the asker and the problem explained inside the comment.

```
add_filter( 'request', 'q363618_modify_request_query' ) ;
function q363618_modify_request_query( $query ) {
    global $wp_rewrite, $post; // <=== it is right, however

    // at this point of loading, $post is not setup
    // so it is always null

    if (   ! isset( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! is_object( $wp_rewrite ) 
        || ! $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() 
        || ! isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) 
    ) {
        return;
    }

    // this checking will never got to work
    // at this moment, only can use $query, modify $query and then setup $post
    // eg. $query['post_type]', $query['chapter]' or whatever available
    // in php 7.4.3, it will display error rather than false

        if ( $post->post_type == 'chapter' ){
        if ( empty(get_post($post->post_parent)->post_name))  {

        } else {
            $parentName = get_post($post->post_parent)->post_name;
            $slug = $post->post_name;
            // preg_match('#[0-9]-(.*)#', $slug, $slug);
            // $slug = $slug[1];
            $query['chapter'] = $slug;

        }
    }


    return $query;
}
```

it is being set by a few places, briefly speaking
if $wp_query->posts return false OR if query parameters does not valid or match something

A quick and easy find out why:

run `http//example.com/name/slug_story/id_parent-slug_chapter` and

run `http//example.com/name/slug_story/slug_chapter`

```
add_filter( 'request', 'q363618_trace_request_query' );
function q363618_trace_request_query( $query ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    var_dump($query);
    exit(); // yes, terminate the php continue to work and see the $query at this point
    return $query; // after that, WordPress will think slug_chapter = id_parent-slug_chapter
}
```

Compare 2 queries to see what is left behind and then modify your logic and conditions to give the expected and working $query

If you could create the same query, then the result should be the same and redirect will work.

Comment: It does not working for me

Comment: My problem is want to remove `id_parent`. `post_name` of chapter include `id_parent` + title that chapter

Comment: Ok, I understand now, I am going to update the answer, but still need you to get involved for providing details before solving it.

Comment: I tried your code, but results returned 404 not found.

Comment: Did you add your own conditions, I haven't added the testing logic for you since it is up to your original design. If you just copy and paste, it will not work. What did you try and add for the conditions? I have marked in the comment that you need to add the logic. So, you need to tell us more what did you try actually so that it is not working.

Comment: Yes. I've added logic. I edited the post in the forum and included your code.

Comment: (1) (2) With regex use `'/$regex/'` or  `'#$regex#'` both are correct. You can try ^^.

(3) I have not understood this question of yours. But I am sure my logic correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing.

Comment: for (3), I means, did you put in exact value to see if it filter works for you?

Comment: @CôngTửHuyết I have added debug method. You could use the debug method to see what is wrong in your query. I have also explained why it is 404.

Comment: Your checking have problem, $post is always `null`, it is not yet setup at that moment of loading so `global $post` is also null. So you need to update and use other method to compare. eg. `$post_type = $query['post_type']. If you var_dump($post), you will always get null if you try. If you want to var_dump to see the output, remember to add exit() to stop the script to see. I have added a tracing example.